# Node.js Parallel calls to same child rest service and aggregating response

Tags: node.js, rest

I want to call from a parent rest service a child rest service. The number of times child service is called depends on parameters to parent rest services. Once I call all child service instance concurrently with different parameters. I want to  combine the responses from all instances of child service. I am using below snippet. But I don't want to use timeout. It should either be timeout or when all calls of child service are over which ever is lesser.

```
    for( i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        url=accountID[i] +'+'+sortcode[i] +'+' +accountHolderName[i];

        micro(url ,filter[i],function(resp)
        {
            this.resutlObject[count]=resp;
            console.log("count"+count);
            count=count+1;
        }.bind( {resutlObject: resutlObject} ));
    }//end of for

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("in time out");
        res.end(JSON.stringify(resutlObject || {}, null, 2));
    },500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use Promises. Suppose `service` call returns promise, then you wait while [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) of them are fulfilled. Node.js supports promises starting from [v4](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/). If you have earlier version of node, just use some [library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

```
//Instead of
function micro(url, filter, cb) {
    var resp = "result of async job";//do some async work
    cb(resp)
}

//Modify your service to return a promise
function micro(url, filter) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var resp = "result of async job using `url` and `filter`";
        if (resp) {
            resolve(resp);
        } else {
            reject("reason");
        }
    });
}

//Create a list of service calls.
var promises = [];
for( i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    url=accountID[i] +'+'+sortcode[i] +'+' +accountHolderName[i];
    promises.push(micro(url, filter[i]));
}

//Wait for all off them to fulfill
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(resultObject) {
        //Response
        res.end(JSON.stringify(resultObject || {}, null, 2));
    }, function(reason) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        console.error(reason);
    });
```

Comment: Sorry my English :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [async module](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallel). It's designed to do the stuff you're after. Something like this:

```
var async = require('async');
var collection = [];

for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
    collection.push(
        (function(i) {
            return function(callback) {
                url=accountID[i] +'+'+sortcode[i] +'+' +accountHolderName[i];
                micro(url ,filter[i],function(resp) {
                    callback(null, resp);
                });
            }
        })(i)
    );
}//end of for

async.parallel(collection, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results) // array of results from all requests
})
```

**What happens**

`async.parallel` takes an array of functions as an argument. Each function receives `callback` as an argument. Callback is a function, which takes `error` and `result` as an argument.

After all callback are executed `async` calls the final callback which receives the array of results from all other callbacks.

In the loop we are creating just that, a collection of functions. In this example the code is a bit more complex because we use closure in order to preserve the value of `i` for each of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use async module [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). It provides the parallel foreach loop.

```
var obj = {dev: "/dev.json", test: "/test.json", prod: "/prod.json"};
var configs = {};

async.forEachOf(obj, function (value, key, callback) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + value, "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    try {
      configs[key] = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
      return callback(e);
    }
    callback();
  })
}, function (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err.message);
  // configs is now a map of JSON data
  doSomethingWith(configs);
})
```

here in the example it is reading files listed in parameters. 
similarly you can do for your task